# Get IIS server's time from Response Headers

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

Using Chrome or Firefox extension I want to best guess [this remote server's](http://sand.telangana.gov.in/TSSANDNETBANKING/Masters/Home.aspx) time.

**Here is the dump of one response header in background script `chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener`:**

[image]

I got this stats today at around 12:30 pm IST or 7:00 am GMT

In the `Date` response header I see as `Mon, 23 Jan 2017 06:51:20 GMT`
while the `timeStamp` is "1485414080685.0159" which from this [site](http://www.timestampconvert.com/?go2=true&offset=-5.5&timestamp=1485414080680.877&Submit=%20%20%20%20%20%20Convert%20to%20Date%20%20%20%20%20%20) comes to be `26th Jan 2017 12:31:21`

Which one I can use to guess the server time?

Comment: Please add code and errors as **text** ([using code formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images do not allow us to copy & paste the code/errors for testing. In addition, an image of your code/error does not permit it to be searched based on the code/error contents.  In general, code/errors in text format >>> code/errors as an image >>>>> nothing.  Images should only be used, in addition to text format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text formatted code/error.

Comment: This is a local time. See [How do you derive walltime from timestamp using Chrome's debugger protocol?](//stackoverflow.com/a/39634132)

Comment: @Makyen copy paste of this data isn't working so I had to put this photo